# Partitioning a 1TB Drive in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, lenovo-laptop

I read some posts regarding this, however I am no further forward.

I have recently purchased a Lenovo 310 AMD A12 computer with a 1TB drive. I have started the computer up, configured Windows 10, and installed my anti-virus. The next item on my list was to partition the drive. I went to the Windows 10 partition panel and looked at the C: Drive. I was surprised to find that it could not be shrunk to less than 475GB.

I contacted Lenovo support. They said:

> Partitioning the drive would invalidate the warranty.

I queried this and contacted John Lewis to see if this was true. After 2-3 hours they conceded that the disk could be partitioned:

> Ok the unit`s drive can be partitioned, as long as the recovery
>      partition of the unit is not deleted the warranty will remain active.

So I forwarded some screen shots of the disk management screen
   including the shrink dialogue indicating the restriction. Their answer:

> Ok, Drive D: is the Primary partition which is required for the operating system by default, And the C: drive cannot be shrunk further as it has the recovery partition installed on there, I do apologise for this inconvenience.

And:

> That part I cannot advise on, "moving or resizing" the partition may cause problems in the future therefore I cannot advise on that.

And:

> We are not able to advise on tempering with the recovery partition I'm afraid.

I do not consider partitioning the drive as tampering. But obviously I do not wish to invalidate the warranty on my new computer. So here are some questions:

1. Can anyone give validity to the threat that partitioning the drive will invalidate the warranty?
2. Do people still partition? I wanted to do so, so that I could step up appropriate backups on my WD Passport.
3. Is the recovery partition really 475GB? Where is this configured? How does the system know where the recovery partition is?
4. I have also read that a defrag would line up the unmovable items at the the start of the drive, thus allowing it to be shrunk. Is this true?
5. Why would the manufacturer set the computer up so that effectively it cannot be partitioned? What is the advantage to them? Why would they consider it to be a bad thing to partition the drive?
6. Would a third party partition software be able to partition the drive without impacting on the recovery partition?
7. Should I return the machine and get a refund? If so, can anyone recommend a machine which can be partitioned?

Comment: Provide screenshots

Comment: instead of telling us a story, could you post the technical details of the disk, and what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: If W-10 or W-8 came with the new PC, generally, the recovery partition is ~ 499 Mb, not GB,  EFI partition, about ~ 450 Mb, NOT GB, and the Factory Image recovery partition, is generally ~ 13 GB.  That leaves most of your drive C: at ~ 970 GB.  I will test my Dell, but I can't see why you couldn't set that C: partition size to whatever you need, (and WON'T affect any other partition), provided your used space is smaller than your new size.  And, perhaps you must first defrag, or the space you are eliminating might itself be in-use, depending on how Windows does it.